# Domino 2D board game in XNA

Tags: xna, 2d

New to XNA. Would love to hear your input in how to set up my clases for my Domino game. So far, I have a "BonesSprite" class which has fields like first value, second value, orientation, position etc. I have code on the LoadContent method which creates a List for each bone as shown in the code below.

```
    Background = Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images\Wood"); 

//Load several different automated sprites into the list 
fichasList.Add(new Ficha(Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Images/46"), 
      10, Vector2.Zero, new Vector2(150, 150), 0, 0, true, true));
```

This is what i have so far: http://i129.photobucket.com/albums/p239/itsshortforleo/Untitled-1copy.jpg

I still can't come up with:

1. How to deal 7 bones to each player (I have an empty Player class that i don't know how to fill yet)
2. How to place the 7 bonesprites on the board so that only player 1 can see his bones and not the other players'
3. How to click on one bone to play it on the board on the exact position right next to the other bone and in the correct orientation
4. How can I highlight a bone when i have the mouse over it

The game seemed so simple to me until I started designing the classes. Appreciate your help.

Comment: removed lotus-domino tag as it is not related to your question.

Comment: This question is a bit broad, I think you should really think about each part. Right now, it looks like you're asking us to write most of your game for you. You've listed 4 different questions. If you post them separately, you'll have more luck getting an answer.

Comment: @annonymously Was just feeling a bit overwhelmed as on how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few ideas for your consideration:

You can deal with (1) and (2) simply. Make a Player and Bone class. Add to the Bone a field "owner" so that you can assign a Player to it. You did not write whether it is going to be turn-based "hot seats" or network game, nevertheless you'll get the correct bones to display just by checking their correcponding "owners" in a loop.
These are basics of the object oriented programming, I suggest you to read more about these concepts before starting a game. It won't take much time but it will make your life easier.

(4) First think how to get a correct bone recognized when clicking.

As others suggested you should also split your questions, (1) and (2) can go together, others not.